# Django: How to increment a counter stored in models.py / Database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have created a small counter model `class Counter` to store the amount of times a small survey application has been completed.

I want to increment `SurveyWizardOneCounter` in my models.py from my `def done()` method in my views.py

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Previously I was using Global variables for my counter which I have found out do not work properly with a web app. I am trying to learn how to create and store a counter in my DB. Any help is appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class Counter(models.Model):                
    SurveyWizardOneCounter = models.SmallIntegerField()
    TotalMaxCounter = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
from survey.models import Counter

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    Counter.SurveyWizardOneCounter += 1  # This is where I am trying to increment the counter

    logger.debug('\n\n SurveyWizardOneCounter = %s', SurveyWizardOneCounter)

    for form in form_list:
        form.save()

    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

Comment: A model in django represents a database table with many rows- not just a single data store.  If you haven't done so you really should go through the django tutorial to get an understanding of what a model is and how it works.

Comment: So if not a model, what should I be looking at to store such a counter variable?

Comment: It's ok store it in a model if you need it. Will that table have just one record?

Comment: @Gocht There will be 9 such counters, SurveyWizardOneCounter, SurveyWizardTwoCounter, etc.

Comment: @Deepend, 9 attributes you mean, but in the same `Counter object`.

Comment: You _really_ need to create a `Survey` model with a counter field...

Comment: @ Have a `class Person(models.Model):` to store the results of the survey. Are you suggesting I should store SurveyWizardOneCounter etc in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have 9 different survey counters and you need to increment each counter when a survey is submitted, it would be better if you define a field `survey_wizard_type` with its possible values being `survey_wizard_one`, `survey_wizard_two` till `survey_wizard_nine` and a field `survey_wizard_count` having default value `0` which stores the count for that particular survey wizard. There would be 9 records in your database for `Counter` model then.

**models.py**

```
SURVEY_WIZARD_TYPE_CHOICES = ['survey_wizard_one', 'survey_wizard_two', 'survey_wizard_three', 'survey_wizard_four', 'survey_wizard_five', 'survey_wizard_six', 'survey_wizard_seven', 'survey_wizard_eight', 'survey_wizard_nine']

class Counter(models.Model): 

    survey_wizard_type = models.CharField(choices=SURVEY_WIZARD_TYPE_CHOICES)
    survey_wizard_count = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    total_max_counter = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

Then in your `views.py`, you can use `get_or_create` method for looking up an `Counter` object with the given `survey_wizard_type`, creating one if necessary. Then increment the `survey_wizard_count` by 1 and save that object into the database.

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import F
from survey.models import Counter

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    survey_counter = Counter.objects.get_or_create(survey_wizard_type= 'survey_wizard_x') # x can be any value from one to nine
    survey_counter.survey_wizard_count = F('survey_wizard_count') + 1 
    survey_counter.save()

    logger.debug('\n\n SurveyWizardOneCounter = %s', SurveyWizardOneCounter)

    for form in form_list:
        form.save()

    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

## EDIT

Rahul provided the solution but this is the code I ended up using

**models.py**

```
class Counter(models.Model):

    SURVEY_WIZARD_TYPE_CHOICES = (
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_ONE', 'survey_wizard_one'),
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_TWO', 'survey_wizard_two'), 
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_THREE', 'survey_wizard_three'), 
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_FOUR', 'survey_wizard_four'), 
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_FIVE', 'survey_wizard_five'),
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_SIX', 'survey_wizard_six'), 
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_SEVEN', 'survey_wizard_seven'),
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_EIGHT', 'survey_wizard_eight'),
                              ('SURVEY_WIZARD_NINE', 'survey_wizard_nine'),
                              )   

    survey_wizard_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=SURVEY_WIZARD_TYPE_CHOICES)
    survey_wizard_count = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    total_max_counter = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    survey_counter = Counter.objects.get_or_create(survey_wizard_type= 'survey_wizard_one')[0] # x can be any value from one to nine
    survey_counter.survey_wizard_count = F('survey_wizard_count') + 1 
    survey_counter.save()

    for form in form_list:
        form.save()

    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Rahul, I hope you don't mind I added a few things in case anyone else needs it

Comment: Not at all! It would help others also.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your `Counter` model will store just one record.

```
c = Counter.objects.get()
c.SurveyWizardOneCounter += 1
# Update another attributes if you need
c.save()
```

Or maybe

```
from django.db.models import F

Counter.objects.filter().update(SurveyWizardOneCounter=F('SurveyWizardOneCounter')+1)
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is non-atomic (you could get a race condition). The 2nd option is much better. See the Django recommended way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you use an atomic method to update the field, some of the answers above could have a race condition between update and save. The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields) suggests to use the following method:

```
from django.db.models import F
product = Product.objects.get(name='Venezuelan Beaver Cheese')
product.number_sold = F('number_sold') + 1
product.save()
```